Замена фона темплейта Wordpress
Как поменять этот фон на мои картинки? Где он находиться? Или как его найти? (wordpress - тема astra - шаблон Bestselling Author)

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Начинаем изучать ВП с терминологии. Это необходимо для взаимопонимания.

Хорошо, но это не ответ на мой вопрос.
